# What's wrong with Mercurial in v. 1.4.3?

Tags: mercurial

I've just installed latest 1.4.3 version of [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) and see new status messages for unknown/modified files.

Previous versions showed this for modified files:

```
M README.txt
```

This new version shows some gibberish like:

```
←[0;32;1m file.txt←[0m
```

What is this and how to interpret it?

Also, is it possible to revert to the old style notation?

SOLUTION:

If you happened to enable the 'color' plugin on Windows you'd get above behavior. After I commented the 'color' plugin, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Ansi control codes, ie. codes to change color and other things on terminal.
These codes doesn't work on XP terminal (worked on Dos terminals with ANSI.SYS in config).
Look if there is a setting somewhere to disable colored output.